# Overriding eslint rule

Tags: typescript, eslint

I can't seem to override the behavior of `"no-use-before-define"`. I don't want to be warned when a function is used before defined. I've tried disabling & re-enabling the ESLint service in VS Code but with no success.

[image: warning example]

VS Code Extensions: [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint), [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

**.eslintrc**

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "prettier/react",
    "prettier/standard",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-use-before-define": ["error", { "functions": false, "classes": true }]
  }
}
```

**.prettierrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  semi:  true,
  trailingComma:  'all',
  singleQuote:  true,
  printWidth:  120,
  tabWidth:  2,
  endOfLine: 'auto',
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to use your configs on a small .tsx file after installing several node modules. It seems like the solution is just: rather than

```
"no-use-before-define": ["error", { "functions": false, "classes": true }]
```

it seems you need to use

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": ["error", { "functions": false, "classes": true }]
```

because the error is coming from `@typescript-eslint`.

Answer (score 1):

If all is lost then you can specify rule for a single line using the below command.

```
/*eslint-disable */

//It will disable all the warnings between comments
alert('eslint disabled');

//To enable just add the below line of code.
/*eslint-enable */
```